# Monitor For Disabled Queue On RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, amazon-rds

I would like to somehow get notification of a queue being disabled due to poisoned messages. (The issue is occasional resource contention. Until we solve it, monitoring would help us be aware.) In my case, SQL Server's service broker is running under Amazon's RDS environment, which limits what is available.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same issue, I see no one else has responded.  Our interim solution is to have a job running every 5 mins to just re-enable the queue if disabled.

If you have devised a solution that hasn't been published, I'd love to hear about it.